# Google Tag Manager - Only allowing tags on defined pages

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a couple of tags that inject some HTMl and JS on a page. We only want these tags to be delivered on certain pages as a whitelist while the feature is rolled out, and also have the ability to allow non-technical staff to add new URLs to this whitelist without the need for code changes across three different sites.

I had a look a triggers and adding Page URL criteria to one. Which works for one URL, but these criteria form an AND relationship, so adding more just kills the trigger.

> Fire this trigger when an Event occurs and all of these conditions are true

I have also read about the gtm.whitelist and gtm.blacklist dataLayer params.

```
dataLayer = [{
  ...
  'gtm.whitelist': ['<ID>', '<ID>', ...]
  'gtm.blacklist': ['<ID>', '<ID>', '<ID>', ...]
}];
```

However this the requirement for non-technical users to add locations, as well as creates quite a bit of logic for three seperate dev teams to implement a method of altering the dataLayer on a per page basis.

Can anyone think of a solution to this? At this stage, the only way I see of doing it is adding one trigger per page/path that we want to include these tags. Which will be fine initially as we roll out to a couple of site sections. But that trigger creation and length of triggers on the tag will become quite long eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookup table for your trigger ([google support pages for variable types](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362?hl=en#)) .

That way you will only need one trigger for example, if you can create "White-list trigger" :

[image]

then you can setup your "White-list lookup" variable as either RegEx table or standard Lookup table, e.g.:

[image]

With RegEx you will have more flexibility to whitelist site sections however if you have non-technical people adding URLs to the whitelist you might choose to use standard Lookup table.

A useful link: [Article about RegEx table.](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/the-regex-table-variable-in-google-tag-manager/)